# Android ViewBinding with CustomView

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'd like to use try out the ViewBinding with custom view, for example:

```
MainActivity <=> layout_main.xml
MyCustomView <=> layout_my_custom_view.xml
```

layout_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.example.myapplication.MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/custom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

layout_my_custom_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#2389bb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Line2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: LayoutMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = LayoutMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.customView.line1.text = "Hello"
        binding.customView.line2.text = "World"
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity, I can use the binding to find MyCustomView but I can't further find `@id/line1` and `@id/line2` in MyCustomView. In this case, is it possible to use ViewBinding only or do I have to use `findViewById` or Kotlin synthetic ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's problem? you can use **kotlin synthetic** as `custom_view.line1`

Comment: @EthanChoi Thanks. I know I can use kotlin synthetics or findViewById, but I want to know is it possible to use ViewBinding only.

Comment: make sure you wrap your view with <layout> </layout> tag

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ViewDataBinding.inflate`  doesn't generate of child view accessor inside custom view.

thus, you can't touch **line1(TextView)** via only use `ViewDataBinding`.

If you don't want using `findViewById` or `kotlin synthetic`, `MyCustomView` also needs to apply `ViewDataBinding`. try as below.

#### CustomView

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val binding =
        CustomLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

    val line1
        get() = binding.line1

    val line2
        get() = binding.line2
}
```

#### MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
    setContentView(binding.root)

    with(binding.customView) {
        line1.text = "Hello"
        line2.text = "World"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. So in your opinion, which one do you suggest? Apply ViewBinding in MyCustomView and expose child views as properties? Or use `findViewById` or `kotlin synthetic`?

Comment: @Z.JHung That depends on your needs. If exist `MyCustomViewModel` for `MyCustomView`, `ViewDataBinding` is more effective, otherwise it's better to use `kotlin synthetic`.

Comment: could you also make the val binding in CustomView public, and then access line1 or line2 in MainActivity in the following way: binding.customView.binding.line1? Or is it a bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: Can someone confirm or correct my assumption here:
attachToRoot = true, when using as view inside a normal layout/view (e.g. fragment)
and since we will set it to attachToRoot = false inside the onCreateViewHolder within an Adapter (if we use it as itemView) it does not matter if we have set it to true here

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to return the `CustomView` binding `object`.

```
class CustomView constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : 
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs){
                
        private val _binding: CustomViewBinding = CustomViewBinding.inflate(
                        LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
                
                val binding get() = _binding    
        }
```

And then in your `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
binding.customView.binding.line1?.text = "Hello"
binding.customView.binding.line2?.text = "World"
```

Comment: just remove private from val _binding

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei _binding is private the binding  is the getter of it.

Comment: This is cleaner and for those who want to access all the child views of their Custom View in their fragments without making their Custom View binding object public

Comment: Preferring this. It is less effort when making changes to the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can have setter in your custom view. Since ViewBinding generates binding class for your main layout, it should return you the CustomView class. Thus, you can use the setter you just wrote for changing the texts.

Comment: Sounds like I have to make MyCustomView a more wrapped class. I have to add `setLine1Text()`, `setLine2Text()`, `setLine1Visibility()`, `setLine2Visibility()`,... etc. I might give it a try when custom view is not holding too many sub views.

Comment: Or, for second thought, you can even use `attrs.xml` file to set the attributes. That way, it would be more like a view instead of wrapper class.