# How to use View Binding on custom views

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-viewbinding

View Binding got released as part of Android Jetpack

Docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

My question is, how to use view binding with custom views. Google documentation has only show-cased Activity and fragment.

I tried this, but nothing was shown.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

And then, I used this one, but again, no luck.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I guess maybe I don't target the correct layout inflater for my view but not sure.

Comment: Please refer binding adapters: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Comment: @RuthwikWarrier Could you please elaborate more? cause I am asking about View Binding not Data Binding.

Comment: There is a similar question with valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60425755/7339798

Comment: @RuthwikWarrier sorry to disagree but question is about view binding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding instead of data binding as link provided by you

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Just inform the root, and whether you want to attach to it

```
init { // inflate binding and add as view
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)
}
```

or

```
init { // inflate binding and add as view
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
}
```

which inflate method to use will depend on the root layout type in xml.

Comment: How about inflate view from existing layout resource? Like `init { inflate(context, R.layout.my_view, this) }`?

Comment: `ResultProfileBinding` is referencing to layout resource. In your case, it will be `MyViewBinding.inflate(....)`.

Comment: Should I set the `binding` variable to `null` somewhere, similar to how [they should be implemented in fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)?

Comment: do we need to set the reference to null somewhere?

Comment: The additional binding arguments are the tricky part here, especially `this`.

Comment: in which method we need to set the binding to `null`?

Comment: Do NOT set the bindings to null. There is no need. A Fragment can survive its view destruction. A custom view can't.

Comment: No need to set binding to null in views, only in Fragments. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments

Comment: For example, If you set binding to `null` in `onDetachedFromWindow` you catch a troubles in RecyclerView - sometimes it just temporarily detach and reattach again it's own childrens.

Comment: can use `requireActivity()`

Answer (score 40):

To use the view binding, you need to use the generated binding class not the `LayoutInflater`, for example, if the layout name is `result_profile.xml` then you need to use `ResultProfileBinding` as:

```kotlin
class CustomView @kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
    private var binding: ResultProfileBinding
    
    init { // inflate binding and add as view
        binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
        addView(binding.root)
    }
    
}
```

1. Auto generated class : `result_profile.xml` -> `ResultProfileBinding`(name of layout, appended with `Binding` )
2. Inflate the binding

   ```
   ResultProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
   ```
3. Use `addView` to  add the view in the hierarchy as:

   ```
   addView(binding.root)
   ```

Note: If you are extending from `ConstraintLayout`(is the parent class) then use [constraint set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527407/4936904)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer can be helpful in some parts, but I need a way to use view binding to inflate with root view not adding the view to the root view.

Comment: @EmiRaz if your custom view is created(java/kotlin) then add you custom view in the XML layout and then can directly access your custom view from the `binding` object  as `binding.customview` or if you want to use view binding as it sounds (`how to use view binding with custom views`) then follow the answer. **FYI**: `inflater` is used to inflate new views using the xml layouts

Comment: If you inflate the view itself in the init block (as @EmiRaz is asking) you just end up in an infinite loop where the inflation calls the init block again.  He is asking how to use `CustomViewBinding` inside of `CustomView`

Comment: @Downvoter: may I know the reason of downvote? as I have clearly added the details about how to use custom view with view binding and added the missing details in the OP in comments

Comment: @JasonToms why would it create a loop, have you tested it? as we will be using the generated binding class of the layout in our custom view

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh As I commented earlier, your answer is true in some cases, but imagine that the custom class is not a ViewGroup, for instance, ImageView. so how is your answer applicable to that situation. to be clear, we don't have addView method there.

Comment: @EmiRaz The custom views with layouts are view group not View, View uses `onDraw` to draw on the canvas, I hope this clears the confusions form all the comments :) Read [more in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Thanks, I get what you mean, but assume a condition where there is a CustomView that extends ImageView and you want to Extend that CustomView but it does not have methods you need (Programmatically). you can only set attributes to get what you need from that CustomView. so you have to create a layout and put the CustomView as is it's root view. and you need to inflate that particular XML layout file. is there an approach for that?

Comment: Your parent view is FrameLayout, so simply inflate into `this` as root: `CustomViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)`. Your layout have to be `merge`.

Comment: @EmiRaz I am not sure what's your requirement in the recent comment but I also don't see any issue, `CustomVIew : Imageview` then `SomeVIew: CustomVIew` then you can put the xml tag of `SomeVIew` in layout and use it with the binding, to inflate, just use the binding class though just make sure to not create any cycle if there's any issue then please feel free to ask another question with problematic code :)

Comment: @MiroslavMichalec but my first intention is to use the same flow as docs and In this example, not sure about using  `merge` in this example though it can be appropriate in different scenarios.

Comment: `addView()` is not necessary if you pass in true for the last param. `ResultProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)` See `Androiderson`'s answer.

Comment: in which method we need to set the binding to null?

Comment: @PavelPoley to avoid memory leaks and unexpected behaviour in fragments, do it inside `onDestroyView`, when the view of the fragment no longer exists but the fragment is still there, not required in custom views.

Answer (score 14):

You can initialize the view binding property right away

```
private val binding = CustomViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)
```

Comment: Can it be lazy?

Comment: You can, but I think unless you are doing a heavy binding, you should not make it lazy as it comes with additional overhead

Comment: You can't if your CustomView has as a root a ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to use View Binding with the root view, this is working for me:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private lateinit var binding: CustomViewBinding

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        binding = CustomViewBinding.bind(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you have some other case, because it doesn't work the way you suggest and crashes with NPE, because nothing gets generated for ids inside this custom view layout.

Comment: Could this leak memory? In fragments it's important to de-reference the binding in `onDestory`

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest kotlin answer I can think of. It's a custom view that just wraps a single TextView and provides an `update(s:String)` function to update the text.

```
<!-- view_stub.xml -->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</layout>

// StubView.kt
class StubView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context,attrs,defStyleAttr) {

    val binding = ViewStubBinding.inflate(context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater)
            .also { addView(it.root) }

    fun update(updatedText: String) {
        binding.myTextView.text = updatedText
    }
}
```

The two things I like about this answer are:

1. `binding` is a `val` instead of a `var`. I try to limit the number of `var`s as much as possible.
2. The `addView` is closely associated with the `val binding` using the `also {}` scope function instead of an `init {}` clause, making the instantiation of the `View` feel much more declarative.

One could argue that the `addView()` is really a side effect and should be in the `init {}` section so that it is separate from the declaration of the `binding` val. I would argue the opposite -- declaring a `val` then feeding it to a section of code that needs it does not feel like a side effect to me.

Comment: Why not simply `attachToParent=true` on `inflate()`? Should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataBindingUtil

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context),
        R.layout.your_layout_id,
        this,
        true
    )
```