# ViewBinding with generated CustomViews in Android | android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-viewbinding

I am referring to both questions:
[Android ViewBinding with CustomView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60425304/android-viewbinding-with-customview) and
[How to use View Binding on custom views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433269/how-to-use-view-binding-on-custom-views)

I am currently migrating from Kotlin synthetics to view binding and I am using alot of custom generated views, mainly to ajust the view size when pressed. It looks like the following (prior to that was java code, if I did something wrong while switching to kotlin please feel free to correct me):

```
class CustomButton constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): AppCompatButton(context, attrs) {

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    super.onTouchEvent(event)
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        val regainer =
            AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.regain_size) as AnimatorSet
        regainer.setTarget(this)
        regainer.start()
        return true
    }
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            val reducer = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.reduce_size) as AnimatorSet
            reducer.setTarget(this)
            reducer.start()
            return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            val regainer = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.regain_size) as AnimatorSet
            regainer.setTarget(this)
            regainer.start()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

override fun performClick(): Boolean {
    super.performClick()
    return true
}
```

Unfortunatly all the questions I looked up so far only reffer to a solution including a custom .xml file. My binding in the activity looks like this:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.customButton.//...
}
```

What I am currently getting is an `android.view.InflateException` through that custom view. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement view binding in this case or how to initialize it in the CustomButton class? Any help with this is much appreciated!

Best regards,
Markus

---

This is the stack trace of the error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 13035
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.my.app:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #39 in com.my.app:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.my.app:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #39 in com.my.app:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.my.app:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
at com.my.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:78)
at com.my.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:72)
at com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:59)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0302ca a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:625)
at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4000)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1093)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:994)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:102)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:97)
at com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView.<init>(CustomTextView.kt:13)
... 27 more
```

CustomTextView.kt:13 is this line:

```
class CustomTextView constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs) {
```

MainActivity.kt:59 is this line:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

The activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95"/>

    <com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/mainSubmenuSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/minimum"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:text="@string/textViewSettings"
        android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColorDefault"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textViewS"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.my.app.custom.CustomCardView
        android:id="@+id/mainCardView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cardViewHeightLarge"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/cardViewMarginVertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardViewCornerRadiusLarge"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mainCardView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalLeft"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">
    </com.my.app.custom.CustomCardView>

    <com.my.app.custom.CustomCardView
        android:id="@+id/mainCardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cardViewHeightLarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardViewMarginVertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardViewCornerRadiusLarge"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mainGuidelineVerticalLeft"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">
    </com.my.app.custom.CustomCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your example, you should add your activity layout xml to the question.

Comment: Not sure how view binding is relevant if the error is in inflating the view. The stack trace will give you a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Would be useful if you put the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the stack trace points to View Binding as being the problem here. Instead, it looks like a theme issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0302ca a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:625)
    at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:4000)
```

The first place I'd look is here:

```
<com.my.app.custom.CustomTextView
    android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColorDefault"
    ... />
```

Make sure that you actually define `<item name="primaryTextColorDefault">` in your theme.

Comment: I tested it and removed all those attr referencing lines and I can start this Activity again. I am setting a theme before the binding in `MainActivity.kt:59` happens. In my attr.xml I defined `<attr name="primaryTextColorDefault" format="color|reference"/>` and in the styles i refferenced `<item name="primaryTextColorDefault">@color/primaryTextColorDefaultLight</item>`. Is there a way of still using `android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColorDefault"` in my .xml or do I have to code evreything that uses a themeAttr? Thanks, so far!